# MATLAB 'Gather' on Tall Array Never Terminating

Tags: matlab, matlabpool

I am running R2017a on Windows 10, and using a tall array that was constructed off a Datastore object (that was, itself, constructed from tall arrays built on MATLAB matrices of doubles).

What really bugs me about the issue I'm having now is that all my code used to work fine. One day it simply started hanging when I tried to run it.

This is the block in question:

```
%load
tallTraindat = tall(datastore);
sz = size(tallTraindat);
sz = gather(sz);
numExamples = sz(1);
exampleLen = sz(2);
```

My tall array is a M x ~1700 single array, constructed on this datastore of smaller single arrays. In a loop:

```
write(fname,tallEx); % tall ex constructed by tall(someSingles);
folderNames{end+1} = fname;
```

and then:

```
ds = datastore(folderNames,'Type','tall');
```

As you can see, this is about as vanilla as it gets. But the operation 'sz = gather(sz)' simply hangs forever. It never finishes or returns. My parallel pool has started properly, and the gather operation gets to the point where it prints 'Evaluation 100% complete'. But it goes nowhere from there. If I pause execution, I'm always taken to a point in RemoteSpdmExecutor, line 129 'obj.RemoteSpmdController.drainIO( false );'. This line apparently lasts forever.

EDIT: When I woke up today, it started failing with an error message instead : 'Error using parallel.FevalOnAllFuture/fetchOutputs (line 69)
    fetchOutputs could not concatenate the OutputArguments. Set 'UniformOutput' to false.
        Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.'

EDIT: Re-created my default local parallel pool a couple times. Now it's back to hanging on that same line of code.

Based on all my tests, it seems that my issue occurs whenever I construct a tall datastore from *more than one* tall-array folder, and then construct a tall array off of that datastore.

Tearing my hair out over this one. If anyone even has a suspicion where to look for the source of this problem, I'd appreciate it. I'll try to respond quickly to requests for more info.

Comment: #have you tried using a different data thatn your "standard" one? Just to see if the problem comes with something data related

Comment: Good question. I just tried creating a tall array from in-memory arrays and gathering its size. Seems to work correctly.

Comment: Thus, the problem must be comming from your specific data

Comment: Just tried doing the same process with a tall array created from random data in the same pattern as my script--save to file, create a 'datastore' object, etc. Worked. I am currently re-writing out my data to see if that does anything for the problem. If that doesn't work, I recently changed the script that writes out the data to save more information in fewer files--because it seems to speed up traversal when I'm reading information later. I'm saving tall arrays of ~100,000 x 1500. I will try saving more, smaller files and see if that changes anything. Will post again in a few minutes...

Comment: Didn't change the issue...I still receive this error message now when I attempt to gather anything from my tall array.

Comment: What is the value of `sz`?

Comment: Well, as the result of a call to sz, it's supposed to be a length-2 vector. The whole tall array is ~250,000 x 1793, but I don't know the exact height because I can't gather sz.

Comment: You should know, as it has to be the same size as `datastore`, right?

Comment: The datastore was constructed off a whole bunch of files. But I wrote 2488 arrays with 250 rows, making...622,000, a little bigger than I remembered.

Comment: Use "mapreducer(0)" to force serial execution. If that works, then it confirms it's an issue with the PCT execution environment. You can then try setting "mapreducer(gcp)" explicitly before calling tall(ds). If that doesn't work, then I would double check all of your parallel pool settings and make sure other parallel calculations are working. If the pool seems to be in order, then call MathWorks Technical Support so that a developer can have a look!